# How to add image dynamically?

Tags: php, html, css

I am very new to web development and PHP. May be this is simple question but searched a lot in Internet but couldn't find the solution.

I have this code in my CSS:

```
.categories .cat_sec {
   float: left;
   width: 232px;
   height: 360px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   margin-right: 1px;
}

.categories .cat_sec h5 {
   width: 232px;
   color: #FFF;
   padding: 10px 0px;
}

.categories .cat_sec .cats {
   width: 232px;
   height: 50px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   padding-top: 259px;
}

.categories .cat_sec .cat1 {
   background-image: url(../images/gold/bangles.gif);
}
```

And calling this CSS style in HTML by the following way:

```
<div class="cat_sec"> 
   <h5> <?php echo $mCollections_array['SubCollectionName']; ?></h5>
   <div class="cats cat1">  
      <ul>
         <li><a href="listing.php">Some Text </a></li> 
         <li><a href="listing.php">SomeText</a></li>
         <li class="viewall"><a href="listing.php">View All</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have to change the image dynamically from the server. But i couldn't get any idea about changing the image in this line of code `<div class="cats cat1">`. In this `cat1` represents the image already defined.

How do I add the image dynamically in the above code?

Comment: Are you saying you want to change the `background-image` property, or you want to change the class associated with the `div`?

Comment: For manipulating the DOM after PHP has processed your file you need to work with JavaScript. I recommend you to have a look to the jQuery-Framework. http://www.jquery.com

Comment: @tsujp If i have 5 image in the database i need to add those dynamically in the page.

Comment: @Vino So what does cat1 have to do with this? I am just trying to clarify to I can write a correct answer for you. You know that if you are adding images based on php you have to use existing CSS classes?

Comment: @tsujp If you see in the css style code cat1 is just representing the static image. How to use existing CSS class to add the image?

Comment: I still don't understand mate. Do you want new `<li>` / `<div` elements, or do you want to edit `cat1`?

Comment: Sorry man.. I want to edit cat1..

Comment: Do you have access to .htaccess?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23013/discussion-between-vino-and-tsujp)

Comment: You want to change the `background-image` defined for `cat1`? Or do you want to set `cat2` to `div`?

Comment: Yes i want to change the background-image defined for cat1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inner CSS:

```
<div class="cats" style="background-image:url('your/path/to/image');">  
  <ul>
     <li><a href="listing.php">Some Text </a></li> 
     <li><a href="listing.php">SomeText</a></li>
     <li class="viewall"><a href="listing.php">View All</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this but the image gets hidden. I couldn't see any images

Comment: Be sure that your path is correct. Take a look to your result html page.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said to me: **You want to edit a CSS file with PHP**

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584388/how-do-i-edit-an-external-css-file-with-php), [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) annddd [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/)

You can also embed PHP into the CSS file to do these kinds of things for you.

**working on answer now**